# Firewall en debian jessie 8

Tags: linux, debian

Buen dia.

Que tal, alguien sabe si debian jessie 8, tiene algun firewall por defecto?

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque  No es sobre programación, es sobre características de una distro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A riesgo de llevar un cachete por responder una pregunta tan vaga, y que, además, no versa estrictamente de programación, comentaré que prácticamente cualquier distro GNU/Linux implementa por defecto el firewall iptables, que forma parte del proyecto [netfilter.org](https://www.netfilter.org/)

No soy usuario de debian, pero por defecto iptables suele venir configurado para permitir todo el tráfico. Puedes ver las reglas implementadas con el comando (requiere permisos de administrador):

```
iptables -nvL
```

que, como digo, si por defecto está configurado para permitir todo el tráfico arrojará algo así:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

En realidad iptables no es más que la aplicación, en línea de comandos, que permite configurar las tablas implementadas en el propio kernel, mediante la creación de reglas contenidas en cadenas. Hay que tener claro, precisamente, que se filtran los paquetes en el propio kernel, a nivel de red.
En la web hay mil manuales interesantes de cómo configurar unas reglas básicas, no me explayaré en ello; yo lo que suelo hacer es generar un script inicial mediante algún generador de los que también existen en la red (como soy usuario de GNU/Slackware [éste](http://www.slackware.com/~alien/efg/)  me va muy bien, y si necesito implementar alguna regla específica la voy añadiendo a demanda.
Ten presente que si creas una regla por línea de comandos es sólo útil para la sesión actual; por ello es útil un script, que puedas ejecutar en cada inicio. Corríjanme los usuarios de Debian si no es así, pero para correr un script al inicio (en este caso, el que hayamos generado en la web, y guardado con el nombre, por ejemplo, mi.script.iptables.sh) asumo que no se necesite más que (como usuario root, o con sudo para obtener privilegios elevados temporalmente):

1. Dar al script permisos de ejecución.
2. Copiarlo en la carpeta /etc/init.d/
3. Ejecutarlo al inicio como daemon:

   ```
   sudo chmod +x mi.script.iptables.sh

   sudo mv mi.script.iptables.sh /etc/init.d/

   sudo update-rc.d mi.script.iptables.sh defaults
   ```

   Suerte.

Comment: Es correcto GuardabosqueS, viene con un iptables vacio, eso era lo que queria saber, muchas gracias

Comment: Un placer, zereft